# .toLocaleDateString is not working

Tags: javascript

```
var period = "2016/12"
var d = new Date(period);
var x =(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -1)).toLocaleDateString();
```

Comment: Please format your source code. What do you mean by "is not working"? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error message? Do you get unexpected output? If so, what is the current output and what is the expected output?

Comment: Please read about [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and what you can pass to it.

Answer (score 3):

`setMonth` method return the specific number of miliseconds, not a Date object.

In this case, you should try:

```
var x = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -1)).toLocaleDateString();
```

or separate it to 2 statements

```
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -1);
var x = d.toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

As per library setMonth will return **The number of milliseconds**. look into

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth

try this

var x = new Date(d.setMonth(d.getMonth() -1)).toLocaleDateString();

console.log(x);